# Enhancing the given image

Tags: image, image-processing, image-enhancement

I have an image i need to enhance. I can use the techniques such as, power law transformation, piecewise linear transformation, smoothing filters on spatial and frequency domain, noise filters. I can also process a selected region of the image.

The following is the image. I want to reduce or remove the irrelevant marked area and enhance relevant areas.

[This is the link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNss.jpg)

Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this? I can reduce the noise of the image and enhance relevant features but I have no idea how to reduce or remove the irrelevant feature.

Comment: How were you able to determine which parts are relevant and which irrelevant yourself? What distinguishes the relevant parts?

Comment: The image was given to me as an exercise. The relevant and irrelevant parts were already marked on the image. Therefore I do not know the reasoning behind the categorizing.

Comment: and why haven't you asked if you don't know? now you have to guess which is never a good thing. If I were you I'd search for clusters of bright pixels, skipping those of too high brightness. but as you I can only guess...